# Proving $u = \text{prox}_f(x) \iff x - u \in \partial f(u)$

Tags: convex-analysis, solution-verification, convex-optimization

I want to show that $u = \text{prox}_f(x) \iff x - u \in \partial f(u)$, where $f$ is a proper, convex and lower semicontinuous function where $\partial$ is the subdifferential and
$$
\text{prox}_f(x)
= \text{argmin}_{y \in \mathbb R^d} \left\{ f(y) + \frac{1}{2} \| y - x \|_2^2 \right\}
$$

Here's my attempt.

If $u = \text{prox}_{f}(x)$, then
$$
f(u) + \frac{1}{2} \| u - x \|_2^2
\le f(y) + \frac{1}{2} \| y - x \|_2^2
\qquad \forall y \in \mathbb R^d
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\| u - x \|_2^2 - \| y - x \|_2^2\right)
\le f(y) - f(u)
\qquad \forall y \in \mathbb R^d
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\partial f(u)
= \{ d \in \mathbb R^d : f(y) - f(u) \ge \langle d, y - u \rangle \ \forall y \in \mathbb R^d \}
$$
so, $x - u \in \partial f(u)$ means that
$$
f(y) - f(u) \ge \langle x - u, y - u \rangle
$$
Unfortunately,
$$
\langle x - u, y - u \rangle
\ne \frac{1}{2} \left(\| u - x \|_2^2 - \| y - x \|_2^2\right)
= \frac{\| u \|^2 - \| y \|^2}{2} + \langle x, y - u \rangle.
$$
What have I done wrong?

Comment: No, you need a two sided inclusion. If you want to prove that $a=b$ then we need $a\leq b,\, b\leq a$. However, $0\leq 2$ and $1\leq 2$ are both lower bounds of $2$, they are both correct, and they do not imply anything about the relation between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fermat's rule:

$$0\in \partial_u(f(u) + \frac{1}{2}\|u-x\|_2^2) = \partial f(u) + u-x\implies x-u\in\partial f(u)$$

The trick, then, is to justify the fact that we distributed the subdifferential operator through the sum. This is justified since the domain of $\frac{1}{2}\|\cdot\|_2^2$ is the whole space, assuming that $f\in\Gamma_0$.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to state that since $f, g$ are proper, convex and lower semicontinuous functions then $\partial (f(u)+g(u))=\partial f(u) + \partial g(u)$ where $g(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|x-u\|^2$

Comment: Even if the functions $f$ and $g$ belong to $\Gamma_0$, it's not the case that you can distribute the subdifferential, you're wrong if that's your claim. It comes from domain qualification conditions which are trivially satisfied because $\frac{1}{2}\|\cdot\|^2$ has full domain. Of course everything I am writing is under the premise that $f\in\Gamma_0$, I took this to be obvious and not worth writing.

Comment: I beg the differ. While it's not an if and only if statement, for $f, g \in \Gamma_0$ where $ri(dom(f)) \bigcap ri(dom(g)) \neq \emptyset$ we can decompose the subdifferential. This is exactly the case for the functions $f,g$ in the question. However if a squared norm would not be in  $\Gamma_0$, even having the entire space as domain would not allow this decomposition. In that case $\partial (f+g) \supseteq \partial f +\partial g$ only.

Comment: The condition $ri(dom(f))\cap ri(dom(g))\neq\emptyset$ is exactly the domain qualification condition I am talking about. It is trivially satisfied with the euclidean norm squared. This is what I've said, sorry if I omitted the subscript on the norm, is that what you disagree with? That is should $\|\cdot\|_2^2$? I thought it was obvious to be honest. I was assuming both $f$ and $g$ are in $\Gamma_0$, I didn't write it because I took to be obvious. By the way, the phrase is "I beg *to* differ".